# php activerecord save does not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, save

I use the latest code igniter (2.0.3) and php-active 0.0.1.

All are working fine except `save()`;

**Code:**

```
if($_POST)
{               
  $entry= Customers::find_by_routeid('4');
  $entry->routeid=5;
  $entry->save();              
}
```

Here's my problem: for some reason that I cannot understand the above code does not work, but if I take the code out of `if ($_POST)`, it works fine.

What I am doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks Damien Pirsy `$this->input->post()` does the trick, but when I uncomment the comments in the code the problems returns.

**The code now is:**

```
if($this->input->post())
{
  $id = $this->input->post('id');
  $oldRoute = $this->input->post('oldRoute');
  $newRoute = $this->input->post('newRoute');

  $entry=  Customers::find_by_routeid($this->input->post('oldRoute'));
  $entry->routeid=$this->input->post('newRoute');
  $entry->save();

  /*
  if($oldRoute<$newRoute)
  {
    for ($i=$newRoute; $i>$oldRoute; $i--)
    {
      $element = Customers::find_by_routeid($i);
      echo $element->routeid -= 1;
      $element->save();
    }
  }
  */
}
```

The elements new IDs (`$element->routeid -= 1;`) are `echo`ing right, but I have the same problem as in the beginning and neither of two saves work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide much details or debug info, so I'll just guess: try using the CI's native post handler instead. You should have `var_dump()`ed the `$_POST` array, see if isset() or not, also, since you're using it as a condition

```
if($this->input->post())
{
  //...
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Since we're talking about Post variables, don't assume they're exactly as you want them. Keep in mind that `$this->input->post('field')` returns **FALSE** when the index is not present; that might well brake your if condition.
Assuming you need numbers to do this, you can do a check like

```
if($this->input->post('newRoute') AND is_numeric($this->input->post('newRoute'))
{
  $newRoute = $this->input->post('newRoute');
}
else
{
  // give it a default value, or raise an error, for example. If you need this
  // variables, and need them to be numbers, you cannot go on in case these 
  // conditions are not met, right?
}
```

And the same for `$oldRoute.`
And yeah, OK, maybe you can write a cleaner code than mine, but you get the picture ;)

Comment: You could have said that before...Please be more detailed, so people could help you better!

Comment: The $_POST is not empty for sure ... I have added echo after and it is echoing...

Comment: Sorry i think that was obvious but give me i minute this->input->post seems to work

Comment: The above code (EDIT section) that i have post the save is working fine but the lines that update entry must be place after the for ...